# sql queries producing the correct number of results from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have created a database, rocks.db, with two tables: yut, and lith

The yut table contains 5 columns: id, type, size, dmu, logb

The lith table contains 3 columns: id, type, con

Examples of the the data in each table are:
yut:

```
1|te|45|0.7|-3.4
2|te|67|0.6|-2.3
3|hg|50|0.9|-1.2
```

lith:

```
1|te|999
2|hg|6564
```

I want to do a query to obtain data from both tables, so I have used an inner join to do this:

```
SELECT yut.id, yut.type, size, dmu, logb, lith.con FROM yut INNER JOIN lith ON yut.type=lith.type WHERE yut.type="te" AND size BETWEEN 0 AND 100;
```

The result I was expecting to get from this query is

```
1|te|45|0.7|-3.4|999
2|te|67|0.6|-2.3|999
```

but instead I got

```
1|te|45|0.7|-3.4|999
1|te|45|0.7|-3.4|999
1|te|45|0.7|-3.4|999
2|te|67|0.6|-2.3|999  
2|te|67|0.6|-2.3|999  
2|te|67|0.6|-2.3|999
```

Why does my code select the same entry three times?

Comment: What is the type of your second column (type)?

Comment: With a regular join I get 1|te|45|0.7|-3.4|999
2|te|67|0.6|-2.3|999 repeated lots and lots of times rather than just 3

Comment: This is not possible. There must be something you don't show us. Only a cross join would produce six result rows (3 x 2) from the two tables (e.g. if you pseudo-joined on yut.type=yut.type mistakenly and limited on lith.type="te" rather than on yut.type="te"), but then you'd see lith.con 6564 in your results.

Comment: @J.Koot: A "regular join"? That's the first time I hear that expression. What makes a SQL-86 implicit cross-join "regular"?

Comment: I was just using the term used by @Walucas

Comment: @J.Koot: Oops, sorry, yes, my question was supposed to go to Walucas of course.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are right, I will edit it